# How can i add a custom uibarbuttonItem to my navigation item in all view controllers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I am trying to add a custom `UIBarButtonItem` to my navigationItem. This button will be available in all my view controllers. so instead of adding it to each `viewDidLoad` method in each `viewDidLoad` I am trying to add it in my application Delegate class in a seperate method that i will call in the `viewDidLoad` method.
Here is my Code:

```
 UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some-header-icon.png"];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height);
UIButton* hellBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[hellBtn setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[hellBtn setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:NO];
[hellBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goToHell) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem* rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:hellBtn];
[self.nav.navigationController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightBarButtonItem];
[hellBtn release];
[rightBarButtonItem release];
```

if I replace the same code blog in any `viewDidLoad` of any viewController and change

```
[self.nav.navigationController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightBarButtonItem];
```

By:

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightBarButtonItem];
```

It works perfectly.
Any Idea Why?

Comment: what is nav? is it a viewcontroller?

Comment: nav is my UINavigationController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a subclass of `UIViewController` for ex. `UIViewControllerBase`, override `viewDidLoad` method and inside it create your  `rightBarButtonItem` and set it. Then make all of your controllers inherit `UIViewControllerBase` - simple OOP scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I used that for my custom Navigation controller to but i forgot to use it for my UIViewController... Thx again for the reminder ;) works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use this `self.nav.navigationController` since `nav` is a `UINavigationController` then dont get the `.navigationController`

Just use `[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightBarButtonItem];`